# Django - how to construct universal clever urls with get parameters

Tags: python, django, url-routing

Here is working Django 1.6.10 view with 3 GET parameters.

```
def list_groupmembers(request):
    success = False
    criteria = {}
    if 'group' in request.GET:
        criteria['member_of_group'] = int(request.GET['group'])
        #vkusers = Vkuser._get_collection().find({"member_of_group": int(request.GET['group'])})#Vkuser.objects(__raw__={'sex': 1})
        success = True
    if 'sex' in request.GET:
        criteria['sex'] = int(request.GET['sex'])
        #vkusers = Vkuser._get_collection().find({"member_of_group": int(request.GET['group']), 'sex': int(request.GET['sex'])})# 62740364 81099158
        success = True
    if 'music_artist' in request.GET:
        criteria['my_music'] = {'$elemMatch': {'artist': request.GET['music_artist']}}
        success = True         
    print(criteria)
    vkusers = Vkuser._get_collection().find(criteria)           
    ctx = {'vkuser_list': vkusers, 'success': success}
    return render_to_response('blog/vkuser_list.html', ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

View is able to handle urls like  `/?group=20548110&sex=1&music=Beatles`  with result showing all users, that belong to group number 20548110, woman, like Beatles music.

The problem here that url pairs are connected with logical 'AND', but if i want logical 'OR' i need to alter code.

Another problem is that i want filters by all fields in database table, not only for 3. I have 50 fields, so i need to write 50 if statements - thats bad. Also i need to check type of every field to construct correct query (handle string, date, number etc.)

The third, i want to set mulitple url values, example  `/?group=20548110&sex=1,2`  1,2 means i want man and women in query.

So: is there a module for Django that solves all these issues?
The most relevant to my question is module Views for Drupal PHP framework, it allows all these without coding.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the URL, they aren't being logical AND'd together, the ampersand symbol (`&`) just delimits key/value pairs in the URL.

With that in mind, there are two ways you can go about this:

1. Munge the values into a comma list in the URL and parse the value in the python, so:

   Given this URL: `/?group=20548110&sexes=1,2`

   ```
       if 'sexes' in request.GET:
           sexes = request.GET['sexes'].split(',')
           # Do something with sexes
           success = True
   ```
2. Use repeated URLs as you should be doing and use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to extract them, so:

   Given this URL: `/?group=20548110&sex=1&sex=2`

   ```
       if 'sex' in request.GET:
           sexes = request.GET.getlist('sexes') # This will return [1,2]
           # Do something with sexes
           success = True
   ```

   Note, that in the above, `sex=1&sex=2` isn't ANDing 1 and 2 together, just stating that both key/values are in the GET request.

Lastly, with regards to searching across 50 fields, it seems like you are trying to build some sort of search. Searching across 50 fields will be *expensive and slow* on the database. You could consider using a search engine with [django, such as Haystack` (which is *amazing*)](http://haystacksearch.org/), or if you want filtering look at limiting the number to a manageable amount based on user feedback.

Comment: Thanx, this approach is working. When i talk about 50 fields i mean ability to use and choose  several of them, not all at once.